# How to Send MS Word Application to Background Using VB Script?

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I have written below piece of code using VBA that creates a blank MS Word document with given no. of pages. The VB function works just fine but the problem is that when it runs it pops up MS Word in foreground despite `wordApplication.Visible = False`. As this function needs to be called inside a loop for N no. of documents, the repetitive flashing of Word screen becomes very annoying to the user.

Is there a solution to this problem? Can the application be sent to background so that it could neither appear in front nor in taskbar and user could go about his work smoothly without distractions.

```
Function CreateEmptyDoc(lngPages, strNewFile)

Dim wordApplication
Dim wordDocuments
Dim wordDocument
Dim objPage

Set wordApplication = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApplication.Visible = False
Set wordDocuments = wordApplication.Documents
wordApplication.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros

Set wordDocument = wordDocuments.Add
'Msgbox wordDocument.Name

wordDocument.Activate

For i = 1 To (lngPages - 1) Step +1
   Set objPage = wordDocument.GoTo(1, 1, i)
   objPage.InsertBreak 7
Next

If wordDocument.SaveAs2(strNewFile, 1) = True Then
   CreateEmptyDoc = True
End If

wordDocuments.Close(0)
wordApplication.Quit

Set wordDocument = Nothing
Set wordDocuments = Nothing
Set wordApplication = Nothing

End Function
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Why would you not put instantiating/quitting the Word application outside the loop? I believe repeatdedly using `Documents.Add`, alone, wouldn't cause as much "flashing".

Comment: This function is being called from another 3rd party (non-vb based) application which processes several documents (.doc/.docx, .pdf etc.) at a time in a loop. Therefore, it has to create a new instance of the VBScript to call this function for every document and once the control comes back to the native application with results, the VBscript variables are no longer available.
And its not just this code, there are other functions as well which perform different sorts of operations on word document. All are facing same problem.

Comment: Given that, I'd say use a library to work directly with the *closed* file, via the Open XML SDK, rather than automating the Word application. If there's no user interaction and you don't want to "bother" the user, don't use the application interface.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is caused by your unnecessary activation of the document. Try:

```
Function CreateEmptyDoc(lngPages, strNewFile)
Dim wdApp, wdDoc, objPage
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  .WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add , , , 0
  With wdDoc 
    For i = 1 To (lngPages - 1) Step +1
     Set objPage = .GoTo(1, 1, i)
     objPage.InsertBreak 7
    Next
    If .SaveAs2(strNewFile, 1) = True Then CreateEmptyDoc = True
    .Close(0)
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Already tried without activating the document to no avail. Removing statement `wordDocument.Activate` doesn't make any difference. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: @Cindy Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please share some pointers or sample code for using OpenXML SDK with VBScript or Javascript.